# How do i pass a table parameter to a function created with load?

Tags: lua, load

Not using load, i would have this source:

```
function dosearch(t)
   t:search()
end
```

and call it with

```
dosearch(my_search_t)
```

However, i want to use load to evaluate a string with the above code inside.

```
codestr = "t:search()"
searchfunc = load(codestr)
```

And finally call it:

```
function callsearch(t)
  -- How to use debug.setupvalue to pass t?
 searchfunc()
end
```

How do i use debug.setupvalue to pass t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function dosearch(t)
   t:search()
end
```

is equivalent to

```
dosearch = load [[
  local t = ...
  t:search()
]]
```

Comment: t isn't yet available when i use load. I can only set it when i invoke dosearch()

Comment: `t` does not need to be available at the moment of `load`.  Just call `dosearch` as usual: `dosearch(t)`

Comment: And, if you care, you can also do `...:search()` and save yourself the `local t =`

Comment: @ATaco - `(...):search()`